# Checkbox filter array values not joining in url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a set of filters using checkboxes. When a box is checked, the value is added to the url and the page content filters accordingly.

As it stands, the filters and script is working, but instead of multiple values being joined in the url and content being displayed, the url is being overridden and only using one value from the checkbox array. For example, if WordPress and XL selected, only WordPress will show in the url. I have had a version of this script working but for select options with no issue, but checkboxes are proving an issue and i'm not sure what i've missed..

Can anyone point me in the right direction? : )

```js
Shopify.queryParams = {};
if (location.search.length) {
  for (var aKeyValue, i = 0, aCouples = location.search.substr(1).split('&'); i < aCouples.length; i++) {
    aKeyValue = aCouples[i].split('=');
    if (aKeyValue.length > 1) {
      Shopify.queryParams[decodeURIComponent(aKeyValue[0])] = decodeURIComponent(aKeyValue[1]);
    }
  }
}

jQuery('.coll-picker').change(function() {
  if (jQuery(this).val()) {
    location.href = '/collections/' + jQuery(this).val();
  }
  else {
    location.href = '/collections/all';
  }
});

/* Specify the input */
var collFilters = jQuery('.coll-filter');

collFilters.change(function() {
  delete Shopify.queryParams.page;

  /* declare an array */
  var newTags = [];
  // console.log(newTags);

  /* This works - if (this) is checked, push value from array : only working for one value though */
  collFilters.each(function() {
      //if (jQuery(this).val()) { // this works for select options
      if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
      newTags.push(jQuery(this).val());
      // var id = $(this).attr("id"); alert("Checked: " + id);
    }
  });

  {% if collection.handle %}
  var newURL = '/collections/{{ collection.handle }}';
  if (newTags.length) {
    newURL += '/' + newTags.join('+');
  }
  var search = jQuery.param(Shopify.queryParams);
  if (search.length) {
    newURL += '?' + search;
  }
  location.href = newURL;
  {% else %}
  if (newTags.length) {
    Shopify.queryParams.constraint = newTags.join('+');
  }
  else {
    delete Shopify.queryParams.constraint;
  }
  location.search = jQuery.param(Shopify.queryParams);
  {% endif %}
});
```

```html
<form class="lmwd-filter" method="post">
  <ul class="clearfix filter-category">
    <li>
      <p>Category</p>
      {% assign tags = 'Ecommerce, Woocommerce, WordPress, Magento 2' | split: ',' %}
      {% for t in tags %}
      {% assign tag = t | strip %}
      <label for="{{ tag }}">
        <input type="checkbox" id="{{ tag | handle }}" class="chk coll-filter" name="{{ tag | handle }}" value="{{ tag | handle }}" />
        {{ tag }}
      </label>
      {% endfor %}
    </li>
    <li><br /></li>
    <li>
      <p>Size</p>
      {% assign tags = 'XS, S, M, L, XL' | split: ',' %}
      {% for t in tags %}
      {% assign tag = t | strip %}
      <label for="{{ tag }}">
        <input type="checkbox" id="{{ tag | handle }}" class="chk coll-filter" name="{{ tag | handle }}" value="{{ tag | handle }}" />
        {{ tag }}
      </label>
      {% endfor %}
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```